# Is there a way to use the "Document Services" from Java?

Tags: google-drive-api

When using Google Apps Script, I can take advantage of the Document Service to create Google Docs programmatically.
Is this service available as Google API so that I can use it on GAE/Java?

Answer (score 0):

No.

The closest you can get right now is to construct your document in HTML, and then upload it with convert=true to create a native Google Doc